# How do I use an array that is of another class type?

Tags: java, arrays, class, null

I have declared a class named Member. I then assigned an array with Member type. When I try to put things into the array, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at HW2_2.main(HW2_2.java:15)
```

This is my code:

```
import c.Member;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class HW2_2 
{
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
         Member[] p = new Member[100];
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         p[0].setID("apple12");
         p[0].setPassword("1234");
         p[0].setFirstname("fname");
         p[0].setLastname("lname");
         p[0].setEmail("*@gmail.com");
     }
 }
```

How do I fix this to the point where I can store data into my array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created an object `p` which points to an array of `Member` objects. This is perfect. However, each object in your array is by default `null`. You cannot simply perform operations on them.

You probably want to do something like...

```
//...
p[0] = new Member(...);
p[0].setId("ID");
//... And so on
```

What's important to learn from here is that an array declaration syntax does not initialize the values of the array itself. That would be impossible, right? How would you pass arguments to the constructors of each one seperately? You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you:

```
Member[] p = new Member[100];
```

it initializes all array members to null (since this is an array of object types).

You need to initialize members if you want them to be usable, therefore here you have to:

```
p[0] = new Member();
```

before you can use that member.

---

If you want to initialize all members at once, you need to loop over all elements in the array and create one for each member; with Java 8 this can be done as such:

```
IntStream.range(0, p.length).forEach(index -> p[index] = new Member());
```

Curiously enough, there is no such method as `<T> void fill(T[] array, Supplier<T> supplier)` in the `Arrays` class.